# JPA latest row per group

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have a table with the following structure:

**Audit Table**

```
|    ID     |   User    |  Log In Date  |    Other Info e.g. IP    |
|-----------|-----------|---------------|--------------------------|
|     0     |     1     |   2017/11/10  |           ...            |
|     1     |     1     |   2017/12/10  |           ...            |
|     2     |     2     |   2017/10/10  |           ...            |
|     3     |     3     |   2017/09/08  |           ...            |
```

In my `AuditRepository` I would like to create a method that extracts the `Audit` with the most recent/latest login date for each user.

**Audit**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Audit")
public class Audit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Instant loginDate

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "User")
    private User user;

    // Other fields
}
```

How can I write a repository `@Query` that can achieve this?

So far I have tried

```
@Query(value =
           "SELECT a FROM Audit a " +
           "LEFT JOIN Audit a1 ON a.loginDate > a1.loginDate AND a.user = a1.user " +
           "WHERE a1.user IS NULL"
    )
```

But I got an exception `QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!`

Comment: Which provider you use?

Comment: @newOne Springboots Spring Data which I presume uses JPA/Hibernate under the hood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'am no have data to test, but I think in `sql` this should be working:

```
SELECT a 
FROM Audit a 
WHERE loginDate=(
SELECT MAX(loginDate) 
FROM Audit 
WHERE user = a.user);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a FROM Audit a 
  inner join a.user u
where a.loginDate = (
        select max(a1.loginDate) 
        from audit a1 inner join a1.user u1 
        where u1.id = u.id and a1.id = a.id
)
```