# list fields of latest version of each record

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables like below for versioning,

`application` table only stores static fields (fields that will never change, in this case only the id of application). And `application_version` table stores the dynamic fields (fields that might change in the future, like it can be renamed etc.) and every time there is  a change, a new row is being added to the `application_version` table. ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47505253/13891083) is a more detailed explanation of this type of versioning design.)

```
application
--------------------
id (PK)
created_at
...

application_version
--------------------
id (PK)
name
description
version
application_id (FK)
...
```

So i'd like to list name, description etc. of all the applications last version.

I'm just able to list max versions of each application:

```
SELECT max(version) FROM application_version GROUP BY application_id
```

How do i make the mentioned query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can use `DISTINCT ON`. `DISTINCT ON` keeps the first row for each grouping, according to the `ORDER BY` clause.

For example:

```
select distinct on (application_id) *
from application_version
order by application_id, version desc
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=62d33899799ca5a914c159203f2d6867).

Comment: What do you think about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47516321/13891083)? i mean it is stupid simple, it's not restricted with just postgresql (i think), it's working and is easy to implement with spring data jpa. Is it too bad in terms of performance or does it have any drawbacks?

Comment: @dolmushcu In terms of the result, your alternative solution works. However, from the point of view of performance it uses a correlated subquery; I tend to think it would be slower if you are processing a massive number of rows. In any case... run your horses! Run both queries and compare.